# Extract all ids from array of objects

Tags: php

With PHP 7.4, I have associative array with objets :

```
$array = [
    1 => Class {
        'id' => 1,
        'call' => true,
    },
    5 => Class {
        'id' => 5,
        'call' => false,
    },
    7 => Class {
        'id' => 7,
        'call' => true,
    },
]
```

I want to extract all the IDs if the `call` attribute === `true`.

After searching, I think I should use the `array_map` function.

```
$ids = array_map(function($e) {
    if (true === $e->call) {
        return $e->id;
    }
}, $array);

// Return :

array(3) {
  [1]=> 1
  [5]=> NULL
  [7]=> 7
}
```

**But I have two problems with this:**

1. I don't want `NULL` results
2. I don't wish to have the associative keys in in my new `array`. I want a new array (`[0=>1, 1=>7]`)

I know I can do it with a `foreach()` but I find it interesting to do it with a single PHP function (`array_walk` or `array_map` ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array which is the `call` value indexed by the `id` and then filter it.  As the id is the index, then extract the keys for the ids...

```
$ids = array_keys(array_filter(array_column($array, "call", "id")));

print_r($ids));

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 7
)
```

Although I think a `foreach()` is a much more straight forward method.

Comment: Damnit I was just going to add that! https://3v4l.org/TIZ7v

Comment: @AbraCadaver, TBH I also had something the similar to yours but been trying to do 3 things at the same time so not got round to checking it :)

Comment: Ha, me too, Teams meeting and beer.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `array_filter` to filter out what you don't want, then you can extract the `id`:

```
$ids = array_column(array_filter($array, function($e) {
                                             return $e->call === true;
                                         }), 'id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) the array with a callback that conditionally adds each item's id to the "carry" array.

```
$ids = array_reduce($array, fn($c, $i) => $i->call ? [...$c, $i->id] : $c, []);
```